# Shell Script to assign command output to a parameter

Tags: linux, shell

I need a Shell Script that looks at the specified directory and assigns the name of the last modified subdirectory to a specific variable.

I can get the name of the latest subdirectory in /apps/ like this:

```
cd /apps
ls -td -- */ | head -n 1 | cut -d'/' -f1
```

But how do I assign the result of the second command to a variable, so I can use the parameter in the further script commands (e.g. mkdir $variable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is called [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
cd /apps
some_dir=$(ls -td -- */ | head -n 1 | cut -d'/' -f1)
mkdir -p "$some_dir"
```

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I needed.

Comment: This assigns to a variable, not to a parameter.  If this is what is desired, the question should be edited.